# How to convert interface to another interface which it implements?

Tags: go, plugins, reflection, code-generation

**In short** - I would like to be able to cast an interface type whose underlying type implements a specific interface to that specific interface.

I am using the plugin package to lookup a New function which looks like so (I have many others the same):

```golang
func NewDomainPrimaryKey() any { return DomainPrimaryKey{} }
```

(This is generated at run-time so I can't just reference it as DomainPrimaryKey)

My lookup and call is like so:

```golang
                plugin, err := plugin.Open("my-plugin")
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }

                symGet, err := plugin.Lookup("New" + pluginName)
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }

                newGenModel, ok := symGet.(func() any)
                if !ok {
                    return errors.New("unexpected type from module symbol")
                }

                anyGenModel := newGenModel()
                genModel, ok := anyGenModel.(GenModel) // **this is where the problem is
                if !ok {
                    return errors.New("unexpected type from module symbol")
                }

                genModelInstance := genModel.Get()
```

In the above I am trying to cast 'anyGenModel' (an interface) to the 'GenModel' interface which it implements, however, this doesn't work.

I am certain it implements this interface because when I do the following, I get no errors.

```golang
type GenModel interface {
    Get() any
    TableName() string
}

var _ GenModel = (*DomainPrimaryKey)(nil) // this doesn't complain
```

How can I do this? I found [this](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/how-to-cast-interface-to-a-given-interface/13997/14) article which I don't think is what I am looking for but seems similar.

Thanks in advance for any help on this - this has become a real blocker for me.

Comment: _" this doesn't work"_ What does it mean? What error message do you get?

Comment: Well you don't get an error message when you do type casting, just that !ok

Comment: if value sored in anyGenModel implements GenModel then the type assertion you claim doesnt work would work, meaning that anyGenModel does NOT implement GenModel.

Comment: Show the exact types you are dealing with. Allowing the assertion to panic may give you more direct information, or just print them out.

Comment: note that `*DomainPrimaryKey` and `DomainPrimaryKey` are not one and the same thing, one implements the interface, the other doesn't. Try `var _ GenModel = DomainPrimaryKey{}`

Comment: @CharlieClarke - regarding "not getting an error" from a failed type assertion, what would you get?  It's an either/or situation - either the underlying type does map to the asserted type or it doesn't.  Thus the `bool` return val.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the underlying type implements both interfaces, this is very straightforward:

```go
package main

import "fmt"

type IFace1 interface {
    DoThis()
}

type IFace2 interface {
    DoThat()
}

type impl struct{}

func (i *impl) DoThis() {
    fmt.Println("I implement IFace1")
}

func (i *impl) DoThat() {
    fmt.Println("I implement IFace2")
}

func GetIFace1() IFace1 {
    return &impl{}
}

func main() {
    i1 := GetIFace1()

    i1.DoThis()

    i2 := i1.(IFace2)

    i2.DoThat()
}
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/zDJPRvO7hqR)

If your code is not working, then I would begin by questioning your assertion that the underlying type of `anyGenModel` actually implements `GenModel` and work from there.